# Link clicks not registering consistently in MVC4 jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I created simple site using MVC4 Mobile template. On index.cshtml I put following links `@Html.ActionLink("CC", "Process", "Home", new { id = "1" }, new { })` and two others with different id.

Controller process links and RouteConfig have correct routing.

When I test the page if I click each time on different link it works ok, but second click on the same link does nothing. I suspect some kind of caching but its not welcome here.

Let me know what to try for this to go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your page divs all have the same id.

```
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
```

jQuery mobile will not fetch a page that it thinks it already is on. If you need to keep the same id, you can put data-ajax=false in your link to "force" it to reload the page. ex:

```
<a href="/foo2" data-ajax="false">Next Page</a>
```

Obviously you will not be able to still use Html.ActionLink to add the custom data attribute, you will have to write your own links or a custom Html helper.

But, if you do this you may run into complications running your web app on iOS in web-app-capable mode because iOS will try to launch Safari instead of staying in the "app."